# How can I build a route handler in Express.js and Axios to handle 2 layers of API requests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, axios

I have a Frontend that will request from the Backend and the Backend will request from an outside API with an API Key. I understand that this is a fairly common practice, although I may be wrong. My issue is that I don't quite understand how to structure my route handlers and middleware for this sort of situation. My server.ts middleware takes the router middleware, the router middleware takes the axios request middleware and that should be returning data to the frontend through the `/by-name/:name` URI. Does my current implementation make sense? Or is there a better way to handle this? I will at some point later on persist data to MongoDB.

### server.js

```
import homeRouter from './routes/home';
import postsRouter from './routes/posts';

app.use('/', homerouter);
app.use('posts', postsRouter);

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.json({ message: err.message });
    next();
});

app.listen(3000);
```

### routes/posts.js

```
import express from 'express';
import { getPostByName } from '../middleware/axiosMiddleWare';

const postRouter = express.Router();

postRouter.get('/by-name/:name', getPostByName);

export default postRouter;
```

### middleware/axiosMiddleWare.js

```
import apiInstance from './axiosInstance';

export const getPostByName = async (req, res, next) => {
    const nameParam = req.params.name;
    try {
        const post = await apiInstance.get(`/by-name/${nameParam}`);
        if (post) {
            res.json(post);
            next();
        } else {
            res.status(404);
            res.json({ message: 'post not found!' });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
    }
};
```

### middleware/axiosInstance.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

const postInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://fake.api.fake/fake/sup/v4',
    timeout: 2000,
    headers: { 'X-Fake-Token': 'FAKEAPI-xxx3a4d6c-333e-333-ab0b-273h47574' },
});

export default postInstance;
```

Comment: 1) Your server will never start because your `app.listen(...)` is inside a middleware function, your middleware function will never be called because your server is not started 2) `middleware/axiosMiddleWare.js` exports no function `getPostByName` you import in `routes/posts.js`

Comment: Those were typos. Fixed both.